# License Key for Java RCP application on VMId

Tags: java, licensing, virtual-machine, rcp

I have an RCP application build on Java 1.6. I am using Virtual Machine Unique ID on a machine as a number to identify a machine uniquely and generate license key based on this number.

I have done basic testing and it seems to work pretty good. I am able to uniquely identify each machine and VMId remains same for multiple sessions (restarts, log off etc). Also if I copy my software installation to a different machine, it doesnt work.

The only apprehension I have is that if this is perfect way to build a licensing algo for an RCP application. Are their any border edge scenarios where this can fail. I am very worried if somebody updates their java software, will that change VMId.

Waiting for expert opinions,

Naveen

Comment: How are you calculating the VMID? are you using `java.rmi.dgc.VMID`?

Comment: yeah, i am using the same function. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the default constructor of `java.rmi.dgc.VMID`

```
public VMID() 
{
    addr = localAddr;
    uid = new UID();
}
```

then you will find that **it depends** on the **`hash`** of the IP address (which will be same for all the machine using the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`). But (and its a **big** but), it also depends on the `java.rmi.server.UID`.

Now as per javadoc:

> An independently generated UID instance is unique over time with
>   respect to the host it is generated on as long as the host requires
>   more than one millisecond to reboot and its system clock is never set
>   backward.

Now there is no machine which is available which reboots in less than one millisecond. The fastest one I have seen are MS-DOS (not sure about the boot time) and Google OS (takes 3-4 seconds, as per their promo).

So, I will feel safe if it is the only factor but I will still test the *`setting the system clock backward`* factor.

---

If I have to use your product on multiple machine but paying only for the one then I would install it on a OS running on VMPlayer or VirtualBox. This way I could distribute multiple copies of your tool. Have you checked this scenario.

Also, on my dev machine I normally have two differnt JDK (a latest one for playing around and a second one for client specific development). The VMID and UID classes are known have some issues earlier with multiple JVMs. Check this: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t131825-can-we-generate-unique-id-from-java.html.

Also, have a look at this javadoc: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/rmi/dgc/VMID.html

Normally, the licensing strategies I have seen are much more involved. Like (on windows machine) creating/using some registry key values, backed by some web service for one time registration, asking user for some salt value (like his/her name, age) and then generating license key from that.

So, finally if you are sure that your products user are not gonna use any virtualization technology (like vmplayer etc), there is no multiple JVM related issue and they might not have internet available for one time activation then go for it.

But keep in mind that for a determined attacker no software is too hard to break as it is evident from the number of pirated/cracked games and softwares available in market.

Comment: ok, so the VMId is different for multiple machine connected to same router and also for standalone machines. Also it stays same between reboots too. The only thing I will test for it would be time travel. I wouldnt care about MS-DOS, it is not my client :). I was just wondering if there is anything I might be missing before actually pushing this to my prod software

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I will check with multiple VM copies issue. Also though my users are not technically  blessed but I wont challenge them to take on my licensing logic. I am also thinking about integrating licensing dongles etc, though not settled how to license it effectively. Thanks for your help

Comment: it seems this may not be a best way. A client with multiple network methods (WIFI, LAN, Modem) will face issue if client switches to alternate network connection or even if he is not connected to the same network which was used when issuing a licensing key